# Babel could not compile ? syntax in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got this issue when trying to compile typescript. It seems babel could not understand "?" syntax at the node.current?.contains(event.target) line

```
export function useOnClickOutside(node: any, handler: any) {
  const handlerRef = useRef(handler);

  useEffect(() => {
    handlerRef.current = handler;
  }, [handler]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event: { target: any }) => {
      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (node.current?.contains(event.target) ?? false) {
        return;
      }
      handler && handler(false);
      if (handlerRef.current) handlerRef.current();
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
    };
  }, [node, handler]);
}
```

[babel compiled error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmbG9.png)

Comment: Does this link help? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining Also, for `??`, see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator

Comment: sorry, but My colleagues has watched it and that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What do you have in the `.babelrc` file? And do you use `babel-loader` in the `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: yeah, i have added babel-loader but this error have exist.

Comment: What "presets" do you have in `.babelrc`?

Comment: i have `@babel/preset-typescript` and `@babel/preset-react` but this error have exist.

Comment: You can add  `"@babel/preset-env"` as well after installing from npm.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include babel loader for ts file in your webpack config like below

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
     test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
   ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing `npm i @babel/preset-env`, you can add `@babel/preset-env` to the "presets" part of `.babelrc`, for example

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": false
        }
      }
    ]
  ]

//some other settings follows

}
```

```
{
  "name": "typescript-near",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.41",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "babel-preset-typescript": "^7.0.0-alpha.19",
    "near-api-js": "^0.45.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-router": "^5.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

my package.json

Comment: this not working , i write this equal to typescript , you can watch my code and give me a recommend

Comment: Restart webpack serve, too. Did you get a different error?

Comment: my colleagues don't know how to restart webpack serve, can u give me a solution

Comment: How did you start the server for React? If you started it from a command line in terminal, you can close the terminal containing it, then run the start command again.

Comment: it does not seem to work for me, any other idea?

Comment: Same error, or a different error?

Comment: i need you give me a new solution for same error

Comment: I started a simple webpack react app, and it works fine with my settings. Maybe we use different versions of webpack? What versions do you have in `package.json`? I have `"webpack": "^4.46.0"`, `"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"`, `"webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"`, `"babel-loader": "^8.2.5"`, `"@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6"`, `"react": "^16.14.0"`, `"react-router": "^5.3.1"`. Maybe I'll try using your versions to see what happens.

Comment: sorry Man but your solution can't solve my error.

Comment: I know that my way didn't solve your problem, that's why I am asking for your versions. Maybe you can show your `package.json` file?

Comment: i was uploaded my package.json file in your answer, you can watch this, thanks bro

Comment: If you changed so many things in package.json, you should delete `node_modules` and package-lock.json` and afterwards run `npm install`

Comment: i think it's my fault when i use `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`  , this morning i started over a new project and this error was solved, thank you so much bro, best wishes for you